# Rails - Sum a column after having already grouped the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a bunch of records that are grouped and I need to sum the columns of all them

When I just to the regular `results.sum(:col_name)` it gives me something along the lines of `{1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 15}`, but I need (in this example) `18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum the values then

```
results.sum(:col_name).values.sum
```